# Detecting gibberish in off_topic intent with IBM Watson Conversation service

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

When constructing an intent designed to capture off topic questions, should we include gibberish phrases (such as 'fgufeu ewe qeweuwe' or other non-valid English)? I'm unsure whether including such words increases or decreases the likelihood of the off topic intent being matched. I'm pretty confident users will try mashing the keyboard to see how the bot responds, but what they enter would never be an exact match for the example gibberish I provide.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to test your model after you have created it. I've seen some instances where people have done this and it appears to work.

> I'm pretty confident users will try mashing the keyboard to see how the bot responds,

From experience you will find that what you believed the user would do, and what they actually do tends to be very different. Especially if you have never done any user testing as you go.

Most users have a clear goal in mind when they hit a chat bot/conversational agent. They will use the bot normally up to the point where they achieve that. Even so someone mashing the keyboard should expect a wrong answer or "I don't know".

Comment: We do have an integration test which makes sure gibberish phrases are detected as off_topic (so that the bot can response with 'I don't know'), and those tests started failing when we added more examples to some other intents. Our first response was to add more gibberish examples to the off_topic intent, but we weren't sure if that would help or hinder (since the new examples would never be precisely matched).

Comment: It's a good point about the user testing, though - maybe our tests are testing for something only a few users will do.

Comment: More user feedback has come that users are typing random keystrokes and being surprised that the intent isn't off_topic. I suspect that users don't mash the keyboard if they're trying to achieve a task, but when exploring the limits of new technology, like a chatbot, they do exactly that.

Comment: This can happen in UAT if you tell the users to "type anything" instead of explaining the purpose of the application.

Comment: Our observations from logging user input is that users are curious and want to test the limits of the technology, even if the purpose is clearly explained in earlier bot messages.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a condition that is always true if others aren't. Like the condition "anything_else"